# Sync API.AI entities from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am building a bot for food ordering. I have saved my food categories (i.e Starters, Meals, Fish, Meat, Pasta etc) in firebase and every food-category can have multiple food-items.

here is my food-item structure in firebase

```
    {
   "-KauXk2E4ma1u70X-h4g" : {
    "food_category" : "fish",
    "food_desc" : "Zander filets in pastry made with beer, tartar sauce",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Homemade fish sticks",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/FISH/Homemade fish sticks.jpg"
  },
  "-KauY4B0pQDgZ_sF92Df" : {
    "food_category" : "meat",
    "food_desc" : "Rindsfiletmedaillons (160 g), Balsamicosauce, fried potatoes",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Medallion of beef with balsamic-sauce",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/MEAT/Medallion of beef with balsamic-sauce.jpg"
  },
  "-KauYG4BcYT5EY36TQM7" : {
    "food_category" : "fish",
    "food_desc" : "",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Gilt head fillets",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/FISH/Gilt head fillets.jpg"
  },
  "-KauYHAaRDF6ZgAFy7U_" : {
    "food_category" : "meat",
    "food_desc" : "",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Münsterhof Food - Burger",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/MEAT/Münsterhof Food - Burger.jpg"
  },
  "-KaucBQaWncdZOc5kat2" : {
    "food_category" : "pasta",
    "food_desc" : "Rigatoni (type of pasta), tomato, pepper, garlic",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Arrabbiata",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PASTA/Arrabbiata.jpg"
  },
  "-KaucGDalMgMRwfCGbvy" : {
    "food_category" : "pasta",
    "food_desc" : "Tagliatelle (type of pasta), tomato, beef",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Bolognese",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PASTA/Bolognese.jpg"
  },
  "-KaucisapOUvgKF2xcjg" : {
    "food_category" : "pasta",
    "food_desc" : "Rigatoni (type of pasta), tomato, basil",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Napoli",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PASTA/Napoli.jpg"
  },
  "-KaucsqbjLVKL3oAv4y3" : {
    "food_category" : "pizza",
    "food_desc" : "Homemade pizza dough, tomato sauce, mozzarella cheese, ham, free-range egg, pesto",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Calzone",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PIZZA/Calzone.jpg"
  },
  "-KaucwQb6NNgkUCg8bZD" : {
    "food_category" : "pizza",
    "food_desc" : "Homemade pizza dough, tomato sauce, mozzarella cheese, basil",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Margherita",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PIZZA/Margherita.jpg"
  },
  "-Kaud7xE6JmQtqhLiLQP" : {
    "food_category" : "pizza",
    "food_desc" : "Homemade pizza dough, tomato sauce, mozzarella cheese, artichokes, hot pepper, mushrooms, ham, olives, oregano",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Quattro stagioni",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/PIZZA/Quattro stagioni.jpg"
  },
  "-Kaue7Wzluk-wy9xys5n" : {
    "food_category" : "starters",
    "food_desc" : "beef-carpaccio, parmesan, olive oil",
    "food_like" : true,
    "food_name" : "Beef carpaccio",
    "food_price" : 45,
    "food_url" : "https://i.scaley.io/768x687/lebijou.io/_jamesapp/food/airhomeCHZH3/STARTERS/Beef carpaccio.jpg"
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sync my food-items (under food categories) from firebase to api.ai entities.

I have done it manually on api.ai like below
http://prntscr.com/fhpme6

Now want to do all this via code (nodejs)
I know there is api.ai provides apis to play with entities i.e https://docs.api.ai/docs/entities (I have used them)
I can extract food-items from firebase and sync data to api.ai entities. But there is a problem. I can't overwrite and/or delete the entities already used in my intents.

Here is the code I have tried so for `FoodSync.js`

```
var util = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var apiai_developer_access_code = "e764e24fa51e4d93bdc1e6bde92d07d8"

class FoodSync {

syncFood(firebaseRef, apiAiRef, callback){

    //Retrieves a list of all entities for the agent.
    var all_entities = 'curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer '+apiai_developer_access_code+'" "https://api.api.ai/v1/entities?v=20150910"'
    var food_category_id = "";
    var all_entities_array = [];
    var all_food_cat_names = [];
    var all_food_cat_entities_id = [];

    var that = this;

    that.execCommand(all_entities, function(error, stdout, stderr){

        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(stdout)
        all_entities_array = jsonResponse;

        for(var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
            var entity = jsonResponse[i];
            if(entity.name == "food-categories"){
                food_category_id = entity.id;
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log('food_category_id: ' + food_category_id);

        if(food_category_id == ""){
            return;
        }

        var food_category_entity_url = that.getEntityUrlWithID(food_category_id);

        console.log('food_category_entity_url: ' + food_category_entity_url);

        that.execCommand(food_category_entity_url, function(error, stdout, stderr){
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(stdout)
            console.log('food_category_entity: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));

            var food_cat_all_entities = jsonResponse.entries;

            console.log("food_cat_all_entities : "+ food_cat_all_entities.length);

            for(var i = 0; i < food_cat_all_entities.length; i++) {
                var food_cat_entity = food_cat_all_entities[i];
                var food_cat_entity_name = food_cat_entity.value.replace('@', '')

                console.log("food_cat_entity_name : "+ food_cat_entity_name);
                console.log("all_entities_array.length : "+ all_entities_array.length);

                for(var j = 0; j < all_entities_array.length; j++){

                    var entity_check = all_entities_array[j];

                    if(entity_check.name == food_cat_entity_name){
                        all_food_cat_entities_id.push(entity_check.id);
                    }
                }

                // Here I got all food-entities id.
                console.log('all_food_cat_entities_ids: ' + all_food_cat_entities_id);

                // Here I am calling the DELETE entity first (then Recreate), Problem is my entity is used in My some of Intents, So upon delete I am getting the error,
                // {
                //   "id": "09e2c21d-b4e3-4a34-a774-eab781c957e1",
                //   "timestamp": "2017-06-09T10:01:19.294Z",
                //   "lang": "en",
                //   "status": {
                //     "code": 400,
                //     "errorType": "bad_request",
                //     "errorDetails": "Some entity names are in use: food-cat-fish"
                //   }
                // }             

            }

        })

        // if(error !== null){
        //     console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        //     callback()
        // }

    })

}

getEntityUrlWithID(entitiy_id){
    // Retrieves the specified entity.
    var entities = 'curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer '+apiai_developer_access_code+'" "https://api.api.ai/v1/entities/'+entitiy_id+'?v=20150910"'
    return entities;
}


execCommand(command, callback){

    console.log('execCommand: called');
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){

        //console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        //console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

        if(error !== null){
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }

        callback(error, stdout, stderr)
    });
    }

}

module.exports = FoodSync
```

Comment: You've included a link o a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It also would be useful if you show what you've already tried and where you got stuck. The Firebase documentation provides a good starting point here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for suggestion. I have added the firebase structure and code what I have done so for.